# Jupyter-Lab, open file in text editor from notebook

Tags: jupyter-lab

From within Jupyter Lab, is there a way to launch a file in its text editor from a notebook window? The use case is trying to view source code of an imported package. Ideally I'd like to be able to set some keyboard shortcut to just 'open file' for function under the cursor.

Comment: I am also looking for a way to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. My use-case is editing a large and possibly externally generated file, with the user repeatedly running some function within the notebook to find any remaining errors. I'd like to put them into a text editor, ideally at the point the error was detected. This seems like a reasonable thing to do, and in that case it's common to find that someone has already coded a solution, but I've had no success finding one.